# JSON gson Parsing with \n

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following to code to parse some JSON:

```
public void parseAvatar() throws IOException, JSONException{    

    is.readInt();

    jo.put("currentHomeId", is.readLong());
    jo.put("homeId", is.readLong());

    byte isInClan = is.readByte();
    if (isInClan == 1) {
        jo.put("clanId", is.readLong());
        jo.put("clanName", is.readString());
        jo.put("clanBadge", is.readInt());
        jo.put("clanRole", is.readInt());
        jo.put("clanLevel", is.readInt());
    }

    byte a = is.readByte();
    if(a == 1){
        is.skipBytes(52);
    }else if(a == 0 && isInClan == 2){
        is.skipBytes(51);
    }else if(a == 0 && isInClan == 0){
        is.skipBytes(43);
    }else{
        is.skipBytes(44);
    }

    jo.put("league", is.readInt());
    jo.put("clanCaslteLevel", (is.readInt() + 1));
    jo.put("maxCcTroops", is.readInt());
    is.readInt();
    jo.put("townHall", (is.readInt() + 1));
    jo.put("userName", is.readString());
    is.readInt();
    jo.put("level", is.readInt());
    jo.put("exp", is.readInt());
    jo.put("gems", is.readInt());
    jo.put("freeGems", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Attack Rating", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Attack K Factor", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Trophies", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Attacks Won", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Attacks Lost", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Defenses Won", is.readInt());
    jo.put("Defenses Lost", is.readInt());

    is.readInt();
    is.readInt();
    is.readInt();
    boolean isPlayerTagAvailable = is.readBoolean();
    if (isPlayerTagAvailable) {
        jo.put("nameTag", is.readLong());
    }
    jo.put("userNameChange", is.readBoolean());
    jo.put("numOfNameChanges", is.readInt());
    jo.put("boughtGems", is.readInt());
    is.readInt();
    jo.put("inWar", is.readInt());

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    ArrayList<DataSlot> rcl = DataSlot.readDataSlots(is);
    String rcll = gson.toJson(rcl);
    jo.put("resourcesCapList",rcll);

    ArrayList<DataSlot> rl = DataSlot.readDataSlots(is);
    String rll = gson.toJson(rl);
    jo.put("resourcesList",rll);

}
```

Last two bits at the bottom should be producing their own array right?.

Here is the output (well part of it)

```
{
  "Trophies": 1262,
  "clanLevel": 1,
  "resourcesCapList": "[\n  {\n    \"value\": 2001000,\n    \"globalID\": 3000001\n  },\n  {\n    \"value\": 1251000,\n    \"globalID\": 3000002\n  },\n  {\n    \"value\": 0,\n    \"globalID\": 3000003\n  },\n  {\n    \"value\": 250000,\n    \"globalID\": 3000004\n  },\n  {\n    \"value\": 250000,\n    \"globalID\": 3000005\n  },\n  {\n    \"value\": 1000,\n    \"globalID\": 3000006\n  }\n]",
  "resourcesList": "[\n  {\n    \"value\": 0,\n    \"globalID\": 3000001\n  },\n  {\n    \"value\": 0,\n    \"globalID\": 3000002\n  }\n]",
  "Attack K Factor": -1653840941,
  "Attacks Won": 0,
  "freeGems": -2037996665,
  "clanBadge": 1526737746,
  "clanCaslteLevel": 2,
  "currentHomeId": 1,
  "clanRole": 2
}
```

Why is the resourceCapList and the resourceList so messed up? Shouldn't they print in a pretty way?

Also is there anyway I can keep the order of the elements the same?

Comment: You're adding resourcesCapList as a String, so it's being treated as a regular old String, with special characters being escaped and such. At the point resourcesCapList is being added, jo.put has no clue that rcll actually contains JSON and so shouldn't be treated as a regular String.  Same for resourceList and rll.

Comment: @blm what is the best fix?

Comment: I don't know offhand, partially because you haven't given us the declarations for things like is and jo. I can guess what is is, and I assume jo is some sort of JSON handling class, but not which one. Anyways, I don't know if it will work, but the first thing I'd try (actually the second thing, the first would be to read the javadocs for whatever jo is, but I can't do that here), would be to call jo.put("resourcesCapList", rcl). You want resourcesCapList to be an array, so try passing its value as an array-like thing.

Comment: `is` is an InputStream class and `jo` is just a JSONObject. @blm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed :)

Thanks to blm for helping with this!

```
ArrayList<DataSlot> rcl = DataSlot.readDataSlots(is);
String rcll = gson.toJson(rcl);
JSONArray rcla = new JSONArray(rcll); 
jo.put("resourcesCapList",rcla)
```

I just converted the String into a JSONArray and it worked :)

Comment: Ok, I can see that that would work, however, you're converting your array to a string and then reparsing it, so there's a lot of unnecessary effort there. JSONArray (at least the org.json one) also has a constructor that takes a Collection, which an ArrayList is, so try `jo.put("resourcesCapList", new JSONArray(rcl))` to do the same thing without turning the array into a string then parsing it.

Comment: And upon further review, org.json.JSONObject.put has a form that takes a Collection as the value, so I think `jo.put("resourcesCapList", rcl)` should work as well.

Comment: Thanks man! @blm you rock! Do you have any advice on making it keep its stupid order? :p

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to preserve the order. JSON objects (in the general sense) are explicitly unordered, and JSONObject (the concrete class in org.json) implements them as a HashMap, which has no implicit order.